# Android ViewPager with dynamic content

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I need a little help to understand how can I change my current implementation of `ViewFlow` to android `v4.ViewPager`. Till now I was populating my views from `ArayLists<?>` with data. Now I need to use the same way I was doing it (if it's possible) and use ViewPager from Android SDK. Any suggestions would be great to understand how it's working, because the examples that I found over internet are using tabs and etc. but I don't need tabs.

Here is how I was using my adapter before :

```
public class WebViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<String> name;
private ArrayList<String> date;
private ArrayList<String> bodies;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public WebViewAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<String> dates, ArrayList<String> body) {
    this.activity = a;
    this.name = names;
    this.date = dates;
    this.bodies = body;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
    return name.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView title, date;
    public WebView body;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.article_title);
        holder.date = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.body = (WebView) vi.findViewById(R.id.body);


        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        holder.title.setText(name.get(position).toString());
        holder.date.setText(date.get(position).toString());
        holder.body.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, bodies.get(position).toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);

    return vi;
}
```

}

And I was using it like this :

```
WebViewAdapter adapter = new WebViewAdapter(this, titles, dates, bodies);
viewFlow.setAdapter(adapter, pos);
```

Now I need the same result with the ViewPager implementation, because I am moving all my project to use Fragments and stuff from the new SDK API.

Any advices / suggestions / help how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of your adapter implement FragmentPagerAdapter. Invflate ViewPager as you did with ViewFlow and set the created adapter on it.
Everything is pretty the same. The only difference - An adapter instatiates fragements and the fragments inflates views.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you wish to achieve .

if you want to use fragments instead of views , check the example called "tabs and pager" inside [actionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) samples (in the fragments project) . it's even compatible with old android versions (before fragments were introduced) .